# Reduce function says: push is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

The code is like this

```
const reducer = (accumlator, currentVal) => accumlator.push( {id: currentVal} );

const ids = ['123', '456'];

// want to get [{id:123}, {id:456}]
const rs = ids.reduce(reducer, []);

console.log(rs);
```

But says:
TypeError: accumlator.push is not a function
at reducer (/home/user/list1.js:2:56)
at Array.reduce ()

Any suggestions ?

Comment: The reducer callback needs to return the array, ie return `accumlator`. `reduce()` takes the returned value from the callback and uses it as the first argument to be passed to the next iteration call to the callback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`push` does not return the array; rather it returns `undefined`. Therefore, for the first iteration, `accumulator` will be the empty array, but for the second iteration it will be `undefined`.

I'd recommend `concat` instead:

```
const ids = ['123', '456'];

// want to get [{id:123}, {id:456}]
const rs = ids.reduce((accumlator, currentVal) => accumlator.concat([{id: currentVal}]), []);
```

...or use `map` for a simpler implementation:

```
const rs = ids.map(id => ({ id }));
```

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer, especially the map implementation ! BTW, in the map way, why it's id => ({id}) instead of id => {id} please ?

Comment: It's because of syntax quirks of JavaScript. `{}` is for defining a code block and it's also for defining an object literal. If you do an arrow function `id => { id }` it thinks there's a code block with the useless statement `id` which means a function that returns nothing, so you'd get an `Array` of `undefined` values instead of what you want. By wrapping in parentheses, this lets the parser know it's an expression instead of a code block, so it'll use `{}` to construct an object with the property `id` instead.